# Add a chart to <div id="whatever">

Tags: gwt, extjs

After an RPC I want to get a specific non-gwt-generated div via DOM to place a chart there.

```
  final VerticalPanel contentHome = new VerticalPanel();

  // ...

  public void onSuccess(String result) {

    if(result == null) {
      contentHome.add(new HTML("Could not load content from server."));
      return;
    }

    contentHome.getElement().setId("inner");
    contentHome.add(new HTML(result));

    Element el = DOM.getElementById("whatever");

    LineChart lc = new LineChart();

    el.appendChild(lc.asWidget().getElement());  // <-- this DOESN'T work
    contentHome.add(lc.asWidget());              // <-- this works
  }
});
```

Somehow

```
lc.asWidget().getElement()
```

only returns

```
< div >< /div >
```

If I add the widget just to contentHome it works. The chart is displayed.

I shall be pleased if anyone could help me on this one

**EDIT:**

Tried this too:

```
    contentHome.getElement().setId("inner");
    contentHome.add(new HTML(result));

    Element el = DOM.getElementById("whatever");
    LineChart lc = new LineChart();

    HTML html = HTML.wrap(lc.asWidget().getElement());

    el.appendChild(html.getElement());
```

but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem, but if your `div` exists in your `HTML` page you can do `RootPanel.get("whatever").add(lc)`. I may have unserstood your question wrong though.

Comment: Is there any kind of error message in console?

Comment: the div `whatever` is contained in the `result` string. so the `RootPanel`does not know about `<div id="whatever">` yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `div` in an [`HTLMPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html)

**Updated:**

```java
HTMLPanel panel = new HTMLPanel(result);
panel.add(lc, "whatever");
```

Comment: `Element.add()` does not exist. I tried a lot of similar stuff like this but nothing works. I event tried something like this: http://maxrohde.com/2012/03/16/gwt-a-widget-that-has-an-existing-parent-widget-may-not-be-added-to-the-detach-list/

Comment: I tried this: `HTMLPanel tmp = new HTMLPanel(result);
        Element e1 = tmp.getElementById("whatever");
        tmp.add(tmp, e1);` but it doesn't work. But thank you anyway

Comment: Sorry again, seems like I'm having trouble today. I accidentally put `e1` in the code instead of putting `lc`. You don't need any `Element` object. Go straight from creating the `HTMLPanel` with `result` (first line of my example) and then add the `LineChart` (`lc`) directly to the `HTMLPanel` in the `div` with `id="whatever"` (second line of my example. As you can see, no `Element` needed.