# Add widget to pure html that is not part of DOM-structure yet

Tags: gwt, extjs

Okay, this really gets annoying since I am sure that GWT should support what I want to do. I asked already two times and I searched the web but I just can't find a solution to my problem.

What I want to do is to load a textfile from the server that e.g. looks like this:

```
<!-- linear_regression.txt -->
<h1>Linear Regression</h1>
Welcome to this chapter. Here, have a graph:
<div id="whatever"></div>
Alright, now have some math stuff:
```

and place a `Widget` - in my case a line chart - into the div `<div id="whatever">`.
I tried a few things..

---

Inside the `onSuccess()` method of an RPC I want to do something like that:

```
public void onSuccess(String result) {

    HTMLPanel tmp = new HTMLPanel(result);
    Element el = tmp.getElementById("whatever");

    el.appendChild(new LineChart().asWidget().getElement());

    contentRoot.add(tmp);
}
```

If I do it like that, my result looks like this:

```
<div id="whatever">
    <!-- Here I want the chart to be placed but all I get is this: -->
    <div></div> 
</div>
```

---

The other approach looks like this:

```
    HTMLPanel tmp = new HTMLPanel(result);
    contentHome.add(tmp);

    Element el = RootPanel.get("whatever").getElement();
    el.appendChild(new LineChart().asWidget().getElement());
```

But here I get an uncaught exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: A widget that has an existing parent widget 
may not be added to the detach list
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel.detachOnWindowClose(RootPanel.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel.get(RootPanel.java:211)
    at ew.client.layout.MainLayout$1.onSuccess(MainLayout.java:95)
    at ew.client.layout.MainLayout$1.onSuccess(MainLayout.java:1)
    ...
```

---

I really get sick of this issue. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Did you check my 2nd update to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15546155/1417997) on your previous question? There's no need to get the `Element` add it as a widget to your `HTMLPanel` with `htmlPanel.add(lineChart, "whatever");`

Comment: omg I just was about posting another desperate try where I first create an iframe-object, iterate throught the element by comparing their tags and blah blah.. your second answer did the job! three lines solved the issue i've been struggling a few days with.. thank you! please post your answer as an `answer` so I can check it as answered. thank you so much!

Comment: I can't believe it that I didn't find this somewhere on the internet. I knew this must be possible but I just couldn't finde these magical lines :D

Comment: Well it's kind of an odd way to do this. Instead of creating `HTML` server side, through RPC and getting the client to insert it in an `HTMLPanel` you could just send whatever text you want from the server to the client and then create everything using GWT widgets (labels, panels, etc.) instead of trying to manipulate divs. GWT abstracts away from using divs.

Comment: the reason why I do this is because I want to write "chapters" into textfiles which will contain on the one hand these `<div>` conainer and on the other hand some LaTeX-like  code which will be interpreted by [mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/). Since I don't want to hard-code these chapters inside the Java sourcecode, I decided to make a RPC that will load my content like this. This way I can modify the chapters more easily in their files. The RPC is needed since I can not load a file inside the GWT framework - so I am using an addtional servlet which does that for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap the `div` in an [`HTLMPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html)

```java
LineChart lineChart = new LineChart();
HTMLPanel panel = new HTMLPanel(result);
panel.add(lineChart, "whatever");
```